# Wrong class is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I have a html like this:

```
<div id="jquery-modal" class="close" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.701961); z-index: 5; height: 653px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
    <div class="myclass" data-multiselect="0" style="height: 633px; top: 10px; display: block;"></div>
    <div class="myclass" data-multiselect="1" style="height: 633px; top: 10px; display: block;"></div>
</div>
```

Please notice the multiselect 1 and 0 in above html
now in my js I am applying the toggle depending on multiselect. problem is that when I click the myclass div with data-multiselect="1" it still grabs the div above it with data-multiselect=0
How can I fix my js to handle this. Here is my js:

```
function onClickingLi(event) {     
    var Selector = $('#jquery-modal').children('.myclass');
    var isMultiselect = Selector.data('multiselect');
    if (isMultiselect) {
         $(event.target).toggleClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        Selector.find('li.selected').removeClass('selected')
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the click event defined

Comment: Your Selector should return an array.

Comment: Since you are clicking on div.myclass directly, you may store `$(event.target).data('multiselect')` in a variable and depending on this value toggle `selected` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#jquery-modal').children('.myclass');`

will fetch you 2 elements (jQuery objects)

```
<div class="myclass" data-multiselect="0" 
<div class="myclass" data-multiselect="1"
```

So when you try to use this `var isMultiselect = Selector.data('multiselect');` it will always fetch the first instance of class which has `multiselect=0`

So you need to mention how the click event is bound and to  which will make targeting the specific class a lot easier.

Comment: To add to what Shushanth said, instead of ```var Selector = $('#jquery-modal').children('.myclass');``` do something like ```var Selector = $(event.target);```

Comment: But we do not what the `event.target` is .. So did not mention that as it does not make sense without the context of the event to which it was bound

Comment: Yeah. I understood why you didn't include that but I assumed the div's with class of ```myclass``` would not have children they could click/target. If they do, then identifying the correct div will require traversing up from the clicked child, or putting some kind of unique identifier on each ```myclass``` into the mix.